# how to get selected date from Kal control?

Tags: objective-c, ios, calendar

1- i want to get selected date from Kal control.
[(https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

i added the codes to my controller:

```
kal = [[KalViewController alloc] init];
kal.delegate = self;
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:kal];
```

In which event can i read the selected date?

2- i don't want to show bottom tableview, is it possible?

i just need calendar view.

Answer (score 2):

in KalViewController.m 
search for the following function:

```
-(void)didSelectDate:(KalDate *)date
{
self.selectedDate = [date NSDate];
NSDate *from = [[date NSDate] cc_dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay];
NSDate *to = [[date NSDate] cc_dateByMovingToEndOfDay];
[self clearTable];
[dataSource loadItemsFromDate:from toDate:to];
[tableView reloadData];
[tableView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

running     NSLog(@"%@",[date NSDate]); in didSelectDate from  KalViewController.m returned the date selected from the kal calendar.

OUTPUT:

```
2011-11-23 14:51:00.345 xx[23467:207] 2011-11-27 08:00:00 +0000
2011-11-23 14:51:01.234 xx[23467:207] 2011-11-28 08:00:00 +0000
2011-11-23 14:51:01.728 xx[23467:207] 2011-11-27 08:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Selected date: %@",to);
```